# How do I fix a child element with absolute position which overflows its parent element

Tags: html, css, media-queries, parent-child, element

I've simplified the code below to make isolate the issue and make it easy to run in your browser.

Basically, I want

1. the *childHeader* element to stay in its absolute position regarless of the scroll within the *parent* element (as it is does in the example)
2. the *childHeader* to fit the width of the *parent* element as the page resizes.

Unfortunately, for some reason the *childHeader* wants to hang over the right side of the *parent* element. How can I fix this?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <title> Calendar </title>       
        <style>
            .parent{
                width: 14.2857142857%;
                float: left;
                border: 1px solid rgb(217, 217, 217);
                overflow: scroll;
                height: 80px;
                text-align: center;
            }
            .childHeader {
                background-color: #000;
                color: #fff;
                font-size: 18px;
                position: absolute;
                width: 14.2857142857%;
                overflow: none;
            }
            .childBody {
                text-align: left;
                padding: 8px;
            }
            @media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
                .parent {
                    width: 100%;
                }
                .childHeader{
                    width: 100%;
                }
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="parent">
            <div class="childHeader">
                30 June 2015
            </div>
            <div class="childBody">
                        info...<br>
                        info...<br>
                        info...<br>
                        info...<br>
                        info...<br>
            </div>
            <!-- repeat 6 times for the week -->
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: It's not clear what you are trying to do...you can't position every header of each day otherwise they will all stack on top of one another. Are you trying to do this - https://jsfiddle.net/nwmc1pmw/1/

Comment: Give parent as relative positioning in css and try

Comment: This feels like the OP wants `position:sticky` but that's not ready for production yet I believe.

Comment: Siddherth - that was it -- .parent{ position: relative;} & .childHeader {width:100%;} Thank you. I didn't know it worked like that.

Paulie_D not exactly what I was going for. Thanks though